# jQuery ajax: Want to sequence the code process

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am getting data from php file through ajax. Based on the data I need to do some processing. I have put a few alerts in my code, and from that I realize that the code outside the ajax is being executed before ajax gets the data. I want the code to be done after the data is received from php file.

Code:

```
$(function () {
    var originalData=""; 
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'data.php',                    
      data: "",                        
      dataType: 'text',               
      success: function(data)          
      {
        originalData=data;
        alert("originalData 1 "+ originalData);  
      }
    });

    alert("originalData 2 "+ originalData);  
    ...
      Processing code
    ...
});
```

The sequence of alerts is:

First : "originalData 2"

Second : "originalData 1"

One option is that I include the `Processing code` inside the `success` function, but I cannot do it because later I want to put a logic such that I can have a buffer of `data` (atleast 4-5 stack deep) because I want user to get new `data` instantly after processing code for current `data`, rather than wait for the `data` to be retrieved through php.

Comment: Ajax uses asynchronous processing model, where once the request to server is sent the client will executing the next statements without waiting for the response to comeback. You need to put all your processing using the data from the ajax call in the success callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax uses asynchronous processing model, where once the request to server is sent the client will executing the next statements without waiting for the response to comeback. Once the server response either the success or failure callback will get called depending on the status of the response.

You need to put all your processing using the data from the ajax call in the success callback.

ex:

```
$.ajax({
    ....
}).done(function(data) {
    //To all you post processing here
}).fail(function(){
    //Do your error handling here
});
```

Comment: I am hoping that I do the same without using the code in call back function.

Comment: you can use `async: false` option provided by ajax, but it is recommended since it will block the browser thread till the response comesback from the server(ie: UI will not get redrawn and UI will freeze without allowing any user interaction)

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for. I wonder how I missed it while googling.

Comment: but I wouldn't recommend using it to anyone

Answer (score 1):

A ajax call doesn't stop the next line execution so you will have to do something like below:

```
$(function () {
var originalData=""; 
$.ajax({                                      
  url: 'data.php',                    
  data: "",                        
  dataType: 'text',               
  success: function(data)          
  {
    originalData=data;
    alert("originalData 1 "+ originalData);  
    myFunction();
  }
});

function myfunction()
{
alert("originalData 2 "+ originalData);  
...
  Processing code
...
}
```

});

Comment: As mentioned in my original question.... I cant put the code in the success callback function.